# Error trying to install Postgres for python (psycopg2)

Tags: python, django, heroku, psycopg2

I tried to install psycopg2 to my environment, but I get the following error:

```
(venv)avlahop@apostolos-laptop:~/development/django/rhombus-dental$ sudo pip install psycopg2
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2,
Downloading psycopg2-2.5.2.tar.gz (685kB): 685kB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.2 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010D -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:0:
    ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: Δεν υπάρχει τέτοιο αρχείο ή κατάλογος
     #include <Python.h>
                    ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-SgfQCA-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2

copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2

copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2

copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2

copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2

copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2

copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2

copying lib/psycopg1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2

copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2

copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/testconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copyng tests/test_bug_gc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_dates.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_copy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_cancel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_bugX000.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_types_basic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_async.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_lobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_cursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_with.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_types_extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/testutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_notify.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_green.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_quote.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_transaction.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/dbapi20_tpc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests

running build_ext

building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.2 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010D -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement

In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:0:

./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>

                ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-SgfQCA-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 148, in main
    return command.main(args[1:], options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 169, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 54: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I also get errors trying to install gunicorn. I followed [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python) example here but nothing. My virtual environment was created using the `--no-site-packages`flag. I use ubuntu 13.10 and greek environment. Maybe it's that?

Comment: Do you have the `python-dev` package installed? If this is a Debian-based distribution (e.g. Ubuntu), try `apt-get install python-dev` and then retry the `psycopg2` installation. It is needed in order to compile Python extensions written in C or C++.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you're using a non-Debian distribution, you'll need to use `yum install python-devel`. The reason for the difference escapes me except to sow confusion and mayhem.

Comment: Good question, should be upvoted

Comment: @RichardD How would I install python-devel for Python3 with yum?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

The `python-dev` package is required for compilation of Python extensions written in C or C++, like `psycopg2`. If you're running a Debian-based distribution (e.g. Ubuntu), you can install `python-dev` by running

```
sudo apt install python-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt install python3-dev
```

depending on your python version (for example, `sudo apt install python3.8-dev`).

After that, proceed to install `psycopg2` in your `virtualenv` environment as usual.

Comment: If you're using python 3 this might not (or perhaps definitely will not) work, you'll need to do `apt-get install python3-dev` instead.

Comment: I had to do `apt-get install python3.5-dev` for python 3.5

Comment: Similarly, I had to do apt-get install python3.6-dev for python 3.6

Comment: same for `python3.7-dev` 

Comment: same for `python3.8-dev`!

Comment: I think there might be a pattern here... 

Comment: same for python3.9-dev

Answer (score 62):

For `Ubuntu 14.04`, from Docker image `python:3.4.3-slim` this combination worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
sudo apt-get install -y python3.4-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libpq-dev

pip3 install psycopg2
```

Note `build-essential` package. It was crucial in my case.

Comment: The build essential did it for me as well. Using Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7.12

Comment: Same here! `build-essential` was the missing piece.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5, same for me – build-essential was missing.

Comment: The `build-essential` was also the missing piece in my WSL Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: this answer worked for me 2 years ag. today it didn't lol

Answer (score 15):

I tried all the solution but only works be

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

after installing lib you can use `import psycopg2`  in python file and then further db connection config

Answer (score 13):

In my case (ubuntu 12.04 with python 2.7 and python 3.4 installed)

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

was not enough. What did the trick was

```
sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev
```

Comment: Great! It was my problem too.

Comment: In my case, `apt install python3.8-dev` saved me

Answer (score 6):

On Amazon Linux within a [python3 venv](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-python3-boto3/) I had to do the following:

```sh
sudo yum install python3-devel postgresql-devel
pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 4):

Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This solved the issue for me. gcc is not pre-installed by default in ubuntu 19.

Comment: this saved our lives trying to install psycogp2 on a ubuntu EC2 server. ty!

Answer (score 4):

For the latest Python 3.7 I had to install `python3.7-dev`:

`sudo apt-get install -y python3.7-dev`

Answer (score 3):

First of all install python-dev

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

And to adecuate use try this:

This is to do with the encoding of your terminal not being set to UTF-8. Here is my terminal:

```
$ echo $LANG
es_UY.UTF-8
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = '(\xef\xbd\xa1\xef\xbd\xa5\xcf\x89\xef\xbd\xa5\xef\xbd\xa1)\xef\xbe\x89'
>>> s1 = s.decode('utf-8')
>>> print s1
(｡･ω･｡)ﾉ
>>>
```

If I unset I got the same error you got:

```
$ unset LANG
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = '(\xef\xbd\xa1\xef\xbd\xa5\xcf\x89\xef\xbd\xa5\xef\xbd\xa1)\xef\xbe\x89'
>>> s1 = s.decode('utf-8')
>>> print s1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-5: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

Comment: The unicode error is simply visualisation-related. The actual fatal error is not being able to locate the `Python.h` header file.

Comment: Thanks, I also had to install server dev:  sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.1   , or 9.3 if using postgres 9.3

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the Ubuntu distribution of Linux and did the following:

Install the latest version of the python3-dev library so C extensions work for python. The first command updates the package list in Ubuntu so the latest version of python3-dev is installed.

> sudo apt-get update

> sudo apt-get install python3-dev

Then I had to install the the missing development library for PostgreSQL: the "libpq-dev" package.

> sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

After that, I was able to finish installing my dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install -y build-essential  after trying everything
with no success this helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried to install psysopg2 version 2.7.3.2 in a virtual environment with python3.8.

The above error occurred.

As it turned out, **python3.8 requires psycopg2 version 2.8 or higher**.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the current virtual environment and create another one. Install the dependencies first then the rest you've been using. This works

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.